# how to auto-ident in Textmate similar to Emacs

Tags: textmate

How do I auto-indent in Textmate similar to the effect of this code under Emacs:

```
(defun set-newline-and-indent ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent))
(add-hook 'c-mode 'set-newline-and-indent)
```

i.e. I don't want to hit return, then tab to indent.  I want to hit return and have Textmate automatically indent to the correct location based on the language.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Textmate should do this automatically. If if doesn't, you can create a custom macro, command, or snippet in the bundle editor which does it for you.

1. First find out the scope of the caret position (`Bundles -> Bundle Development -> Show Scope`). It should look something like `source.ruby string.quoted.double.ruby`.
2. Then create a snippet that contains a newline and a tab.
3. Then assign the snippet to the previously mentioned scope and assign it a shortcut.

If done correctly, your shortcut should trigger the bundle item in the assigned scope instead of inserting a new line.

Look inside the bundle editor at the `CSS -> properties {}(})` bundle item for an example.